# Delete xml file after create a Visual Studio Setup Project

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, installation

All the time when i just create a setup to my Project in Visual Studio 2015 ,just have a xml file.
[image]

What i need to do to delete this file?  I don't choose any xml file

this is screen what i choose in Application Folder :
[image]

Really searched forum etc can't find solution for this . Anyone have the same problem?

**EDIT 1**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>

    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
    </startup>
    <userSettings>
        <c_sharp_od_nowa.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="Login" serializeAs="String">
                <value />
            </setting>
            <setting name="Password" serializeAs="String">
                <value />
            </setting>
            <setting name="Checkbox_rememberme" serializeAs="String">
                <value />
            </setting>
        </c_sharp_od_nowa.Properties.Settings>
    </userSettings>
</configuration>
```

**EDIT 2**

I just said bad . When i just install [image]

It create a exe + dlls + this xml fime. 
How can i hide this xml.

Comment: Is this the app.config file in your project?  Can you post the contents of this file?

Comment: Yes there is i just update main

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setup project is including this file `myproject.exe.config` because you have an `app.config` in your project. If you don't want it, you have to remove the `app.config` from the project. You probably need to re-work parts of your project such that this can be done.

Comment: i just use this for save  account and password when use want and click remember me

Answer (score 0):

you can right click on your main class library and select publish to create setup file from project

or

this link maybe help you.

[link address](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-create-a-setup-file-in-vs-2015)

Comment: Sorry i said bad  my creating install is fine like in your link but when i install my application with this installation it creates dlls + exe and plus this xml file

Comment: sorry,i create simple project with this two way true works and Did not create a xml file

Comment: when i just deleted my app.config it works fine  dunno why but i have to withoutthis file just

Comment: This is because app.config = Myproject.config (xml) file.  Deleting one deletes the other because its the same file.